# Is it better to use multiple UIViewController or one controller to manage 4 tables?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a splitview controller and i'd like to manage more than one table in the detail view (using this [cocoa control](https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLHorizontalSelect), for each section one table). Should I use 4 specific view controller or just one that controls a subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation :

> A UITableView object must have an object that acts as a data source
>   and an object that acts as a delegate; typically these objects are
>   either the application delegate or, more frequently, a custom
>   UITableViewController object. The data source must adopt the
>   UITableViewDataSource protocol and the delegate must adopt the
>   UITableViewDelegate protocol. The data source provides information
>   that UITableView needs to construct tables and manages the data model
>   when rows of a table are inserted, deleted, or reordered. The delegate
>   provides the cells used by tables and performs other tasks, such as
>   managing accessory views and selections.

I would suggest to use four different UIViewController that will **modularise** your code and **easy to managing**  as compared to every thing in a single UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can use number of table view in single base view, but you need to handle it with some tag…like tag value (any integer value) or by name. I think you need to manage with tag and this will happens  like below:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {

if (tableView.tag == ) {
        return value;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

if (tableView.tag == ) {
        return value;
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  if (tableView.tag == ) {
      <#statements#>
  }
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  // Configure the cell...

  return cell;
  }

But in this scenarios you need to handle entire condition gently. And always care about that do not code large statement inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, another wise it will take so much time to initialize that cell at the loading time.